# Example of flex-basis: content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I noticed in the [flexbox specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-flexbox-1-20160301/) that `flex-basis` can be set to `content`.

I'm trying to use that in the html. But it's not working in chrome.

Can someone show me an example for `flex-basis: content`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the `content` value is not yet supported by most major browsers.

Here's a [screenshot from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Browser_compatibility):

[image]

For an explanation about what `content` does, MDN is also helpful:

> **`content`**
>
> Indicates automatic sizing, based on the flex item’s content.
>
> Note: Note that this value was not present in the initial release of
>   Flexible Box Layout, and thus some older implementations will not
>   support it. The equivalent effect can be had by using `auto` together
>   with a main size (width or height) of `auto`.
>
> Note: Brief history
>
> - Originally, `flex-basis: auto` meant "look at my width or height
>     property".
> - Then, `flex-basis: auto` was changed to mean automatic-sizing,
>     and "main-size" was introduced as the "look at my width or height
>     property" keyword.
> - Then, that change was reverted, so `auto` once again means "look
>     at my width or height property"; and a new `content` keyword is being
>     introduced to trigger automatic sizing.
>
> *<sub>source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Values</sub>*